# how to parse remote document?

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help parse the document from the Internet.

```
import pprint
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import Node

import requests

addr = requests.get('http://fh79272k.bget.ru/py_test/books.xml')
print(addr.status_code)

doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(str(addr))          # load doc into object
                                                  # usually parsed up front


mapping = {}
for node in doc.getElementsByTagName("book"):     # traverse DOM object
    isbn = node.getAttribute("isbn")              # via DOM object API
    L = node.getElementsByTagName("title")
    for node2 in L:
        title = ""
        for node3 in node2.childNodes:
            if node3.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE:
                title += node3.data 
        mapping[isbn] = title

# mapping now has the same value as in the SAX example
pprint.pprint(mapping)
```

This script does not work. error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\VINT\OPENSERVER\OpenServer\domains\localhost\python\parse_html\1\dombook.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(str(addr))          # load doc into object   File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1960, in
>   parse
>       return expatbuilder.parse(file)   File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 908, in parse
>       fp = open(file, 'rb') OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ''

XML:

```
<catalog>
<book isbn="0-596-00128-2">
<title>Python & XML</title>
<date>December 2001</date>
<author>Jones, Drake</author>
</book>
<book isbn="0-596-15810-6">
<title>Programming Python, 4th Edition</title>
<date>October 2010</date>
<author>Lutz</author>
</book>
<book isbn="0-596-15806-8">
<title>Learning Python, 4th Edition</title>
<date>September 2009</date>
<author>Lutz</author>
</book>
<book isbn="0-596-15808-4">
<title>Python Pocket Reference, 4th Edition</title>
<date>October 2009</date>
<author>Lutz</author>
</book>
<book isbn="0-596-00797-3">
<title>Python Cookbook, 2nd Edition</title>
<date>March 2005</date>
<author>Martelli, Ravenscroft, Ascher</author>
</book>
<book isbn="0-596-10046-9">
<title>Python in a Nutshell, 2nd Edition</title>
<date>July 2006</date>
<author>Martelli</author>
</book>
<!--
 plus many more Python books that should appear here 
-->
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building the XML from the response object, not from the text in the body. Instead of `str(addr)`, use `addr.text`:

```
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(addr.text)
```

Also, using an XML parser to handle HTML is bothersome. Try using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).